# "Review Suggested Edits"...I answered wrong!

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

So I just broke the magical Rep 2000 barrier, and decided to try to do some good by Reviewing edits.

...Well, I clicked "Approve" on an edit, and almost immediately thought better of it (please note: I'm not trying to make mistakes like this, but I am new to reviewing these edits, and I messed up. I will try to be more careful in the future).

Is there a way for me to change my Edit response?

The Edit in question is: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7379400

I don't think I should have improved it. The edit should have been submitted as an answer instead :(

Comment: Come back to it later, check if it was approved. If it was, roll it back (but hopefully it shouldn't be). Just be happy it wasn't an audit and take some more time in the future when reviewing (we all make mistakes, I just got off a review ban).

Comment: Damn it, Cody!!

Comment: But, seriously, it was rejected, you learned your lesson, and life goes on. Also, all the stuff @KevinBrown said.

Comment: So I can drop the "One staple in the back of the hand per mistake made on SO" policy? Yay! I was running out of Band-Aids

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is to not stress about it. You're new to reviewing, and mistakes happen all the time - this is one of the reasons we have the review audits. In this particular case the edit [has been rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7379400).

The important thing to remember is that it takes several people to approve for the edit to be committed, and a post can still be edited again after that. So as per Kevin Brown's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288233/review-suggested-edits-i-answered-wrong#comment166522_288233), if you do it again in the future just keep an eye on it.